# How to create a function with a variable number of 'for' loops, each with a distinct index?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, indexing, mathematical-lattices

#### The Problem:

Consider a *d*-dimensional simple cubic lattice.

If the lattice has width *L*, then the number of lattice sites is *L<sup>d</sup>*. I want to create a list that contains all the positions of the lattice sites, for a general *d* and *L*.

For example, when *L = 2* and *d = 2* this would be [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)].

#### My Attempt:

Whilst I can do this for general *L*, I have not been able to generalise the dimension *d*.

Below is my solution for *d = 3* using three `for` loops.

```
def Positions(L):
    PositionList = []
    for i in range(L):
        for j in range(L):
            for k in range(L):
                PositionList.append([k, j, i])
    return PositionList
```

It's easy to see how I would change it to increase or decrease the dimension *d* as I could simply add or remove the `for` loops, but obviously it is very tedious to write this out for large *d*.

I thought about using a recursive `for` loop, so I would only be using one `for` loop for any *d*, but I don't know how to do this whilst preserving the indexing I need to write out the positions.

#### In Conclusion:

Is it possible to have a variable number of `for` loops, each one having a distinct index to solve this problem?

Or is there a better solution without using `for` loops?

Comment: Recursion is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is using `itertools` cartesian product:

```
from itertools import product 
L, D = 2, 2 
print(list(product(list(range(L)), repeat = D)))
```

> Result

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: You beat me to it @Seyi Daniel. I was just thinking about using a combinatorial function to solve this problem in one line when I was reminded of the `itertools` library. Thank you anyway, hopefully this will be helpful for the next person to have this problem

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is indeed the way to go

The idea is:

If you assume your function works for d-1 dimensions, then you can take that result and append to each of the results the value of `i` (the loop variable), and do that repeatedly for each value of `i`.

The base case is when d=0, in that case you have just a single, empty result.

Here is how that can be coded:

```
def Positions(L, d):
    if d == 0:  # base case
        return [[]]
    return [
        [i] + res  # prepend i to the results coming from recursion
            for i in range(L)
                for res in Positions(L, d-1)
    ]
```

If you are not familiar with the list-comprehension syntax used in the final statement, then here is how you would do it without that syntax:

```
def Positions(L, d):
    if d == 0:  # base case
        return [[]]
    positions = []
    for i in range(L):
        for res in Positions(L, d-1):
            positions.append([i] + res)
    return positions
```

Comment: that's FP way. and its major drawback is, all this interim storage can't be good, for any non-negligible output size. but it can all be avoided by appending  by one tuple  at a time into the final result list *in the innermost loop* (innermost among the `d` nested loops built through recursion), building up the tuple on the way down. then the space requirement is just one d-size tuple (besides the output of course -- and it can be just print out, instead, for no-space output; impossible with the FP approach). can it be done in python?

Comment: @WillNess, with `yield`.

Comment: aha, and each function (besides the bottom-most) would use `yield from`? isn't there some costs for that `d`-long chain of  re-yieldings? in e.g. C we'd just link-in each tuple, if the output were a linked list, say. I was wondering if _that_ was possible in Python.

Comment: sure that is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

you use recursion. the first part is the base case and the second part is to add every number from 0 to L-1 for every term in the lattice for the lower dimension

```
def positions(L,d):
  if d==0:
    return [()]
  else:
    return [(x,)+positions(L,d-1)[y] for x in range(L) for y in range(len(positions(L,d-1)))]
```